# How to get the exact moment when a fragment is no longer visible to the user?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to do a wizard to save a sheet with simple informations.

I spent hours looking for solutions, but all of them didn't work.

I have an activity whose layout has just a ViewPager. This activity has two fragments (A and B).
When the first one is complete, the user clicks on the "Next Button" on action bar and then the second one should appear. At this point, when the user finish the process, he clicks on "Save Button" and the sheet should be saved.

I've tried to do this in several ways, but none of them have worked:

For now, I'm trying to know when the fragment A turns invisible (i.e., when the fragment B is occupating all the screen), then I will be able to send its data using an interface (like explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)). The problem is that I don't know which method to use...

I've already tried all the lifecycle methods but none of them has worked.

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem overriding the method `[setUserVisibleHint(boolean)][1]` and checking the parameter! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewPager.onPageScrolled()` to detect when the user scrolls the ViewPager.
Check the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#onPageScrolled%28int,%20float,%20int%29) Ref Docs

I've modified Reference Docs example to demonstrate storing information from the first fragment into a variable in the parent activity when the user scrolls. I've included *all* the java and xml files, so you should be able to just cut and paste into a new project to get it running.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private boolean mStoredCheckBoxState;
    private TextView mStoredCheckBoxStateNotification;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStoredCheckBoxStateNotification = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.storedCheckState);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                FragmentA frag = (FragmentA)mAdapter.getItem(0);

                // Store the checked state value from Fragment A 
                mStoredCheckBoxState = frag.getCheckBoxState();

                // Update the UI with the stored CheckBox state value  
                if (mStoredCheckBoxState == true) {
                    mStoredCheckBoxStateNotification.setText("Checked");
                } else {
                    mStoredCheckBoxStateNotification.setText("Not Checked");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private FragmentA mFragA = new FragmentA();
        private FragmentB mFragB = new FragmentB();

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return mFragA;
            case 1:
                return mFragB;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stored Checkbox State : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/storedCheckState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Not Checked" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentA.java**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private CheckBox mCheckBox;
    private boolean mCheckBoxState;

    // Getters
    public boolean getCheckBoxState() {
        return mCheckBoxState;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        mCheckBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckBoxState = isChecked;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**fragment_a.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment A" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**fragment_b.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment B" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @SoundConception! But I resolved this in another way. After all day trying to do this I finally got it! I just added some `getMethods` at my fragments and then used them in my `PageViewActivity` at the `onPageSelected` method: `(FragmentA) adapter.getItem(position)).getMethod())`. I just don't needed to know the exact moment when the a fragment is no longer visible.

Comment: Actually, I solved a problem and got other! So I still need to know the exact moment when a fragment is no longer visible.

Comment: Are you using a FragmentPagerAdapter or a FragmentStatePagerAdapter for your ViewPager to handle the fragments? The code examples in the reference docs for these two classes give good examples of their use.

Comment: I'm using `FragmentPagerAdapter` because there are just two fragments in `ViewPager` and their data are very small, so I chose keep them in memory instead to build them every time.